# Selenium can't find class

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium with Python and I can't find the class depths:

```
element = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class = "depths"]')
```

or

```
for a in browser.find_elements_by_class_name('depths')
```

from this link https://www.binance.com/trade.html?symbol=TRIG_BTC

You can see the HTML with the class here: https://pastebin.com/CWEchN2f

I have more functions using Selenium in my code with another websites without any issue.

Comment: You need to use this xpath :- //div[@class="depths"]

Comment: I got empty result with this one too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working code (Updated):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get("https://www.binance.com/trade.html?symbol=TRIG_BTC")

elements = ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".depths")))
print(elements)
```

Output:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="08e1be69e2b4b7eff2d76c4b8420a287", element="0.8669087765654466-1")>, 
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="08e1be69e2b4b7eff2d76c4b8420a287", element="0.8669087765654466-2")>]
```

You have 2 elements with such class (here is JavaScript code for checking):
[image]

Then access separate element in the loop or by index in the list (elements).

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thanks for your help but I got the same result. If I print the result I got: []

Comment: @ClaudioCanalesVicencio, I have updated my answer. Check it, please.

Comment: I got empty result as well. ty

Comment: @ClaudioCanalesVicencio, I have posted a working code.